# Batch query in sql and display results only in one header

Tags: sql-server

I have this sql command:

```
Select OrderId FROM [dbo].[Order] where WarehouseOrderId = '#KR133725'
Select OrderId FROM [dbo].[Order] where WarehouseOrderId = '#KR136721'
```

Then the result like this:

```
OrderId
229291490377
OrderId
229584591308
```

How can I make it to result like this:

```
OrderId
229291490377
229584591308
```

Comment: Is it Excel or SQL Server. Tag the correct one. If it is Excel how you wrote select statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select OrderId FROM [dbo].[Order] where WarehouseOrderId in ( '#KR133725', '#KR136721')
```

Comment: It is in excel file and i cant do it like that.

Comment: There are hundreds of select query